# I want to save new txt not covering the old one.there are 12 old txt. how to save 12 new ones when the loops over

Tags: python-3.x

I have a certain numbers of file in a specific directory, that I want to save like a new file after some operation was done on them.
My actual code that attempts this is:

```
fileList=glob.glob('MODIS_temp_2010./*.txt')
f_len=len(fileList)
for k in range(0,f_len):
  filename=fileList[k]
  modis_temp=np.loadtxt(filename)
  modis_temp=np.array(modis_temp)
  modis_temp=np.where(modis_temp==0,np.nan,modis_temp)
  modis_temp=modis_temp*0.02
  modis_temp=modis_temp-273.15
  np.savetxt('modis_temp.txt',modis_temp)
  plt.imshow(modis_temp)
```

How I need to change it so will work?

Answer (score 0):

Look from I understood you want to save your files after you have modified them in the same directory. 
Because you want to save the new ones in the same directory, because of OS and File Systems needs they must be distinguishable. This is done by using different names if we are in a specific directory, or using  different directories for the same name file. 
In your case we need to create a new name and you can append for example the current date, indicating the time of editing so the new twelve files will stay with the old one.

```
import datetime

today = datetime.datetime.now() #current date
date = today.strftime('%d_%m_%Y')
newname = filename.split('.')[0] #we are taking only the name not the extension part
newname += date
```

Now you have a new file name indicating when the file was edited. A better solution will be create a new directory with the editing date for name, and write in the files so they will maintain the same name.